# Does multiclassing into Specialist Wizard need you to pick at character level 1 or wizard level 1?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, wizard, multi-classing

Okay, I want to create a Mystic Theurge in 3.5, going Cleric/Wizard 3/3.  I would start with 3 levels of Cleric and then do 3 levels of Wizard.  On the Wizard side I also want to be a Wizard with School Specialization.

In the School Specialist description it says

> The wizard must choose whether to specialize and, if she does so, choose her specialty at 1st level. At this time, she must also give up two other schools of magic…

Does this mean as a 1st level character I must choose the school, *or* when I take my first level of Wizard I must choose the school?

Comment: Welcome! One question post here can only have one question in it, so I removed the second question. Please do post you question about multiclass specialist wizard restrictions and cleric spells in a fresh question post!

Comment: Thanks - will post the second question seperately

Answer (score 8):

When you take your first level of wizard.

Class descriptions nearly always refer to class levels. When they refer to character level or to total hit dice, they do so in a way that is not ambiguous.

Comment: Correct answer, I agree. 1st level of wizard not character 1st level.